# Unit Testing Angular service file using Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-services

I am new to angular and jasmine environment. Facing some issue in jasmine testing when testing my service.ts file

**Angular Function in .ts file**

```
getBenchmarkingOptInData(assessmentId: string): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this._benchmarkingOptedIn.value === null) {
      return this.httpClient
        .get<IPbAssessmentMetadata>(
          `/api/metadata`
        )
        .pipe(
          catchError(() => {
            return of(null);
          }),
          map((response: IPbAssessmentMetadata): boolean => {
            console.log('response :', response) // `response` is displayed ex: {a:1}
            if (response) {
              this._benchmarkingOptedIn.next(response.consentToContribute);
              return response.consentToContribute;
            }
          })
        );
    } else {
      return of(this._benchmarkingOptedIn.value);
    }
  }
```

**Unit Test :**

```
const httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<HttpClient>('HttpClient', [
    'get',
    'post',
    'put',
    'delete',
  ]);
....
....
beforeEach(() => {
let service = new ServiceName()
})
it('should call the getBenchmarkingOptInData create api', () => {

    const id = '55c0e8ef-dfa4-4c30-bf3a-5f5b1b69a275';

    const assessmentcreationResponse = require('../../../mock/assessments/assessments-api-response.json');

   // `assessmentcreationResponse` contains {a:1}

    httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(assessmentcreationResponse));
    service.getBenchmarkingOptInData(id).subscribe(res => {
      expect(httpClientSpy.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        `/api/metadata`
      );
      console.log('RESPONSE : ', res); //HERE I AM GETTING empty response, But I was expecting the data {a:1}  
     
      //expect(res).toBe(assessmentcreationResponse);
    });
});

Is it because of the RxJS operators in between (pipe, map), how to mock ?
```

I am Not sure, what I am missing, Please help, and also let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: Try using HTTPTestingController to test the HTTP (https://medium.com/better-programming/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf). As for why what you have is not working, are you sure `this._benchmarkingOptedIn.value` is `null` to go inside of the if statement for your tests? Maybe put a console.log inside of that if and see if it gets logged.

Comment: @AliF50, I have modified the code, can you please check once more, as the console inside the service function is displaying the object {a:1}, but the same is not happening in .spec file

Comment: I am thinking in your unit tests, it does not pass the first `if` condition of `if (this._benchmarkingOptedIn.value === null) {` and goes to the else clause. Put a console.log directly after this and see it being logged.